# Parse: Dashboard: Reset Login Password

Tags: passwords, change-password, password-recovery, parse-dashboard

I'm doing the migration from the Parse Server; and a few months ago I've changed the login password for the Parse Dashboard. Is there any way to reset it or a customer service that could help me with this issue (?)